# Why does a kalman filter work better in a simulation than in real life?

Tags: optimization, simulation, python

I am trying to use a classical
[*Kalman filter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)
for getting indoor location.  I am using geolocation API of HTML to get
latitude, longitude, position accuracy and speed.  I am also using the
smartphone's accelerometer to get acceleration.  The Kalman filter
combines this sensor data.  I tried making a simulation in python with
gaussian error comparable to actual measurement.  The GPS measurement
has accuracy of around 20 meters.

In simulation using Kalman filter I was getting consistent accuracy of
1-2 metres for 10000 iterations.  When I tried applying it in real life
the location just stays at the same place.  There is almost no movement
when I move from the original location.

My question is **how can I make the Kalman filter respond to the movement?**

It should at least follow the direction even if absolute location may not
be accurate initially.
I looked at the histograms of the measurements. I tried using 2 methods:
(a) I measured the position and aceleration after a very small interval say 1 millisecond.
(b) I created a listener for when the position updates

In method b) the measurements follow a distribution  very close to gaussian. In method (a) the measurements are gaussian but there is a sudden jump. Although (b) should be better but that takes a while to update so I will get fewer iterations for kalman filter hence lower accuracy. It looks like accelerometer is updating very fast but gps is not. I think  need a way to deal with the missing measurements of gps. Also the two methods are tested at two different locations but origin is the  same.

histogram for method (a) (in 1 dimension):

[image: histogram for method (a) in 1 dimension]

histogram for method (b) (in 1 dimension)
[image: histogram for method (b) in 1 dimension]

Here is the python snippet:

- `vx, vy` are velocity,
- `ax, ay` are acceleration, and
- `kx,ky` are the output position of the Kalman filter.
- `numpy.eye(n)` is just $I_n$, the identity matrix.

```python
class KalmanFilterLinear:
    def __init__(self, _A, _B, _H, _x, _P, _Q, _R):
        self.A = _A  # State transition matrix.
        self.B = _B  # Control matrix.
        self.H = _H  # Observation matrix.
        self.current_state_estimate = _x  # Initial state estimate.
        self.current_prob_estimate = _P  # Initial covariance estimate.
        self.Q = _Q  # Estimated error in process.
        self.R = _R  # Estimated error in measurements.

    def GetCurrentState(self):
        return self.current_state_estimate

    def Step(self, control_vector, measurement_vector, accuracymatrix):
        # ---------------------------Prediction step-----------------------------
        predicted_state_estimate = (
            self.A * self.current_state_estimate + self.B * control_vector
        )
        predicted_prob_estimate = (
            self.A * self.current_prob_estimate
        ) * numpy.transpose(self.A) + self.Q
        # --------------------------Observation step-----------------------------
        innovation = measurement_vector - self.H * predicted_state_estimate
        innovation_covariance = (
            self.H * predicted_prob_estimate * numpy.transpose(self.H) + accuracymatrix
        )
        # -----------------------------Update step-------------------------------
        kalman_gain = (
            predicted_prob_estimate
            * numpy.transpose(self.H)
            * numpy.linalg.inv(innovation_covariance)
        )
        self.current_state_estimate = (
            predicted_state_estimate + kalman_gain * innovation
        )
        # We need the size of the matrix so we can make an identity matrix.
        size = self.current_prob_estimate.shape[0]
        # eye(n) = nxn identity matrix.
        self.current_prob_estimate = (
            numpy.eye(size) - kalman_gain * self.H
        ) * predicted_prob_estimate
        # -------Creating the Kalman filter--------------------------
        timeslice = 0.0043
        state_transition = numpy.matrix(
            [[1, timeslice, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, timeslice], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
        )
        control_matrix = numpy.matrix(
            [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
        )
        observation_matrix = numpy.eye(4)
        initial_state = numpy.matrix([[20.0], [0.0], [20.0], [0.0]])
        initial_probability = numpy.eye(4)
        process_covariance = numpy.matrix(
            [
                [timeslice ** 4 / 4, 0, timeslice ** 3 / 2, 0],
                [timeslice ** 3 / 2, 0, timeslice ** 2, 0],
                [0, timeslice ** 4 / 4, 0, timeslice ** 3 / 2],
                [0, timeslice ** 3 / 2, 0, timeslice ** 2],
            ]
        )
        measurement_covariance = numpy.eye(4) * numpy.array([20, 0.2, 20, 0.2])


kx = 0.0
ky = 0.0

kf = KalmanFilterLinear(
    state_transition,
    control_matrix,
    observation_matrix,
    initial_state,
    initial_probability,
    process_covariance,
    measurement_covariance,
)

# --------updating the kalman filter----------------------

control_vector = numpy.matrix(
    [
        [0.5 * ax * timeslice * timeslice],
        [ax * timeslice],
        [0.5 * ay * timeslice * timeslice],
        [ay * timeslice],
    ]
)
accuracymatrix = numpy.eye(4) * numpy.array([accuracy, accuracy, accuracy, accuracy])

kf.Step(control_vector, numpy.matrix([[x], [vx], [y], [vy]]), accuracymatrix)

kx = kf.GetCurrentState()[0, 0]
ky = kf.GetCurrentState()[2, 0]
```

Comment: @discretelizard I'm not sure I would be so quick in dismissing this as computer science.  You might argue it fits in OR, Stats, SciComp, Engineering, Math, StackOverflow, but it could also be a question about the inner workings of a Kalman filter, in which case CS could be the right place.

Comment: @PålGD The topic of the question might fit, but the question seems to be about getting a particular piece code to "work" on a smartphone, and hence is more suitable for [so]. This could turn out to be a question about Kalman filters, but it could also be a question about Python or the specific smartphone device, and given that the main information given is inside a lengthy code-block, this question did not seem suitable for [cs.se] as is, and suitable for [so]. However, I can reopen the question if Dhanraj Mahurkar clarifies that this is a conceptual question about Kalman filters.

Comment: fair enough ...

Comment: I want to clarify that this is about Kalman filters and not about python .The code is just to help users understand the inputs.Would it be better if I remove the code and just include the inputs?

Comment: It's currently also posted on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64114709/781723.  Please pick only one place where you want it to appear, not both.  If you want to ask here, we accept conceptual questions, but not questions about code.  Debugging why your code isn't working is out of scope.  I don't know why it is working better in simulation than in reality; it could be an implementation issue, it could be the quality of the data, it could be a conceptual problem, and I'm not sure how we'd tell given the information available here, or if that is on-topic here.

Comment: At minimum you'd need to tell us what you've already done to try to debug it and show us plots, figures, etc., with the results of the experiments you've already tried.  Have you validated whether the real-world measurements have Gaussian error?   Have you tried running the same code on both simulated data and real-world data?  Have you tried visualizing the sequence of events on a map, for both simulated data and real data?  I'm not sure that asking for how to debug code or an algorithm is going to be on-topic here.

Comment: I have made some changes to the question. Also I have removed the question from stack overflow. Please have a look.

Comment: I don't need to debug the code.Just need some advice on how to design the filter like changing the process covariance etc.

Comment: You've discovered that your simulations don't match the actual data, so it's time to do new simulations.  Also, I think it would be helpful to see the results of the other suggestions I made, e.g., visualizations of the data.  I think you're also going to need to be more precise about what you mean by "stays at the same place".  Forever?  Or is it just delayed?  By how much?  Ultimately I'm not sure that this is a good fit for this site, as this site is not built for interactive debugging (unless you can provide everything needed in the first revision of your question).

Comment: Perhaps you are right D.W , I need a new simulation.I realised that in real life the gps measurements are updating quite slowly compared to accelerometer. So i need to build a simulation where gps data is delayed. Also I read an article that inorder to deal with these 'masked measurements' you need to implement a separate mechanism in kalman filter. I do have a real time visualisation ready which shows your location on a map.I will post here soon.